# R Write data in a file

Tags: r

I'm trying to save data in a file, but every time I hit the save button, it saves it but keeps deleting the data I already have there. What could be the problem?

```
 saveData <- function(data) {
data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
if (exists("responses")) {
  responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
} else {
  responses <<- data
}

 write.csv(responses, file = "read.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: add `append = TRUE` to `write.csv` and check `?write.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
write.csv(responses, file = "read.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Or

```
saveData <- function(data) {
data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
write.csv(data, file = "read.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: You can avoid checking the `response` object if you write the csv with `append = TRUE`.